# distribution of two variables each follows scaled chi-square

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, hypothesis-testing, chi-squared

Let $S$ is a test statistics and $w_1$ is a weight. $w_1 S$ follow a scaled $ c_1 \chi^2_{d1}$.
Then let $w_2 S$ follow a scaled $ c_2 \chi^2_{d2}$.

What is the distribution of $w_1 S +w_2 S$ ?

We can re-write this as;
$T_1=w_1 S $ and $T_2=w_2 S $, then what is the distribution of
$ \pi T_1 + (1- \pi)T_2 $ ? where $\pi$ is a constant.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to result in a [Generalized $\chi^2$ distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_chi-squared_distribution). Not something particularly nice.